# Trying to display different print() messages depending on the number variable i.e. Temperature

Tags: swift

I am basically brand new to swift. So, this may be a ridiculous question. I have been at this for too long. My lectures from my professor cover it, but the way it has been explained was a little difficult for me to make sense of.

I am trying to have swift print different phrases depending on the temp variable. If I  have only the first set of code and change the variable to -x it works fine without the rest of the code.
I'm not entirely sure where it gets completely wrong. I get a load of errors on it, I know that.
Thank you for any and all help in advance.

````
    if temp < 0 {
     
    print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
    }
    
    if temp = 0 ... 20 {
    
        print("Very Cold Weather")
    }
    
    if temp = 21 ... 40 {
    
        print("Cold")
    }

    if temp = 41 ... 60 {
    
    print("Normal")
    }

    if temp = 61 ... 80 {
    
    print("Nice")
    }

    if temp = 81 ... 90 {
    
    Print("Warm")
    }

    if temp >= 91 {
    
    print("Hot")    
    }
    ```
````

Comment: In swift `=` means assignment and you use `==` to test for equality but you can't check against a range like that, either split it into two, `temp >= 21 && temp <= 40` or use `contains`, like `(21...40).contains(temp)`

Comment: `if temp = 61 ... 80` parses as: `if (temp = (61 ... 80))`, that is, it's trying to assign a `Range<Int>` (lowerbound 61, upperbound 80) to a variable called `temp`. The result of that assignment expression is trying to be treated as a boolean value for the `if` to use. Except Swift's assignment operator, `=`, is a statement, not an expression. It doesn't "result" in any value.

Comment: That makes far more sense to me now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that you are using the wrong operator for comparison `=` instead of `==`, and if you would like to check if a range contain a value what you need is the pattern matching operator `~=`. i.e: `if 0...<21 ~= temp {` but what you are really looking for is a switch:

```
let temp = 76
switch temp {
case .min ..<  0: print("Too Cold for Outdoors")
case    0 ..< 21: print("Very Cold Weather")
case   21 ..< 41: print("Cold")
case   41 ..< 61: print("Normal")
case   61 ..< 81: print("Nice")
case   81 ..< 91: print("Warm")
default: print("Hot")
}
```

This will print:

> Nice

Comment: Ah okay! This makes more sense seeing it this way. I figured the way it was set up would be making it overly complicated for how simple it should be.
Thank you.